# Need assistance with understanding this make file for debian linux

Tags: linux, debian, make, dpkg, makefile

I have this code in make file and i could not get it

```
CHECK=dpkg -L $1 2>&1 >$(NULL) || $(APT) install -y $1
install.dpkg.%:
    $(call CHECK,$*)
```

I want to know

1. I have read that `$*` means all dependencies. here does it mean whatever is written in `%`
2. in `dpkg -L` what is the use of it, to me it look like outing is going to null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q1:**
Im not 100% sure about the $* since there are soo many variants. I usually use $@ to select the targets, but maybe $* is more correct.

**Q2:**
I can say about your question 2 that this is standard bash. The call

```
cmda || cmdb
```

(Which is an or statement) can also be understood as

```
if cmda doesn't succeed, then try to call cmdb and see if that will succeed
```

that means that when you call

```
dpkg -L $1 2>&1 >$(NULL)
```

The result of this is being used to decide whether the second command

```
$(APT) install -y $1
```

should be executed.

So, i believe this means, if the program is not installed, install it!